# Find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E(X_1\mid X_1+\cdots+X_n)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let $X_1,..,X_n$ be i.i.d integrable random variables. Find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E(X_1\mid X_1+\cdots+X_n)$.

I was thinking of using the Basu's theorem in some way. If I can claim that $\frac{X_1}{X_1+\cdots+X_n}$ is ancillary , then it is independent of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then since the $X_i$'s are i.i.d, and we know that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i}{\sum X_i}=1 \implies E\left(\frac{X_1}{\sum X_i}\right)=\frac{1}{n}$ which goes to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. But I don't think ancillarity makes sense here. How to approach this otherwise?

Comment: It makes sense to call a statistic ancillary only in the context of some specified family of probability distributions. And the same applies to sufficiency, which is a concept used stating the hypotheses of Basu's theorem.

Comment: $X_1/(X_1 + \dots + X_n)$ is definitely not independent of $X_1 + \dots + X_n$.  Intuitively, you can infer some information about whether  $X_1 + \dots + X_n$ is large or small by looking at whether $X_1/(X_1 + \dots + X_n)$ is small or large, respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the sequence $X_1,\dots,X_n$ is i.i.d, that sequence has the same joint distribution as any permutation of the sequence.  Then for $k=1,\dots,n$ the values
$$
a_k := \mathbb E[X_k \mid X_1+\dots+X_n]
$$
are all equal, and their sum is
$$
n a_1 = \sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb E[X_k \mid X_1+\dots+X_n] =
\mathbb E[X_1+\dots+X_n \mid X_1+\dots+X_n] = X_1+\dots+X_n.
$$
That means
$$
a_1 = \frac{1}{n}\left(X_1+\dots+X_n\right) .
$$
For limit as $n \to \infty$, apply the law of large numbers.